# Determine who changed file using solely apache logs

Tags: wordpress, apache, security, logging

I was searching for a little while and yet I wasn't able to find anwser for this. I own webhosting with huge amount of files in it. I don't have shell access and lately some automated malware started to put malicious js into my wordpress core files. When I removed it all, of course it came back almost instantly.

And here's my question: where can I see the source of those edits?
Let's say I have this file `wp-admin/js/custom-background.js` and some file (probably vulnerable plugin) keeps to modify it (I'm almost sure it's not cron job, just checked)...

What could be possible solution for that?

Comment: The main problem here is if it was a plugin vulnerability, the author/source will be Apache/PHP since it will be a script firing the edit.

Comment: that's the issue... even if I reinstall whole installation of my wordpress I'll probably also take malware with me in my backup... I have to determine somehow which file was it.

Comment: The best thing I can suggest is to install a fresh copy of Wordpress then export your post, articles and page and import them on your new wordpress. usually the exporter will also include the plugins from official repository, no idea if it will pick up those from third party sources. Next is to go to the plugins, disable plugins and see if problem reoccur.

Comment: Install the fresh copy somewhere else on a new domain/sub domain. Or if you have root access on your webserver, disable write privilege an d turn on php error log reports (dump to an error log file).  This will break some of your plugins but you can get a picture on what PHP file have caused a failure in writing

Comment: that's gonna take years, taking in notice I'd have to export dozens of articles from a few years... I was hoping there's a better way

Comment: I updated my last comment :)

Comment: Thanks for interest. Sadly Im limited as I dont have shell access. What's interesting, though, I scanned many of my files (including plugins) against wp repo and the ONLY thing that's edited are many javascript files, inserted with malicious javascript code. I cannot see a single modified php file...

Comment: @Nathan, the best solution is, to hire WordPress expert who can help you certainly.